# Scrimba: Unknown require error when importing a .jpg file

Tags: reactjs

I am using Scrimba and trying to import a jpg file into a react component. When I run my code I am getting an unknown require error.

Link to my Scrimba: https://scrimba.com/c/cv8qyvc2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your image location is up one directory. You should updated your import statement for the image to look up one directory.

```
import tiger from '../tiger.jpg'
```

Comment: I updated my import statement to say import tiger from '../tiger.jpg' but I am still getting the same error.